Find the degree of $\sqrt[5]{81}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[81]{5})$.
I am struggling to find the answer to the following problem from the lecture notes for Galois Theory course.
Question : Find the degree of $\sqrt[5]{81}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[81]{5})$.
My attempt : It's like I have to find $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta) : \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)]$ where $\beta = \sqrt[5]{81}$ and $\alpha = \sqrt[81]{5}$. Now we have
$[\mathbb{Q}(\beta) : \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)] \leq \text{deg}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\beta) = 5$. So we have the possibilities as $1,2,3,4,5$. Now 1 is definitely not possible. I have to somehow decide between $2,3,4,5$. I need help with the rest

$[\mathbb{Q}(\beta) : \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)]$ only make sense if $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$, and that's not the case here.

ahh makes sense.

@PlayerUnknown1098 It's important to note though that it doesn't mean the problem is wrong. What you are asked is to find $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)]$.

I see. This makes sense. The reforumation indeed makes it easier.

The reformulation of the question is technically wrong. Since $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ and $\beta \notin \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ we don't have any inclusion. Indeed what we are asked to find is $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)]$.
To find this we use simple tower law
$[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}][\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)]$.
Now it is easy to see that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}] = 81$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}] = 5$ and since they are relatively prime we have $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}] = 81 \times 5$, and hence by the equation above we have $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)] = 5$.
